# Get value of BLOB field and show/hide a label based on it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, blob

I'm calling some data from my Oracle table and I have a field which is called 'image1' which is a BLOB field.

Sometimes an image is input into the field and others it's not. I need a way to read the BLOB field to see if its a blank and then show/hide my label based on its contents.

Here's my source code

```
        query = OracleConn.CreateCommand()

        query.CommandText = "select * from articles"

        DataTable = New DataTable()
        OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(query)
        OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)

        GridView1.DataSource = DataTable.DefaultView
        GridView1.DataBind()

        If DataTable.Rows(0).Item("image1") = "" Or DataTable.Rows(0).Item("image1") Is Nothing Then

            lbl1.Visible = False

        End If
```

This doesn't seem to do what it's suppose to do.

Any ideas how i can accomplish my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test to see if image1 is DBNull:

```
If DataTable.Rows(0).Item("image1") Is DBNull.Value Then
```

Comment: Got this to work in the end - I needed to insert a Null value into the field - Thanks